# Android: error: [Hilt] Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am new to android and I try to develop an app using Dagger-Hilt, however I ran into the following error when building the app.

```
.../trackandtrace/feature_location/LocationService.java:7: error: [Hilt] Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (com.google.dagger.hilt.android)
public final class LocationService extends android.app.Service {
             ^
  See https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
```

My build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false

}


android {
    namespace = "com.example.trackandtrace"
    compileSdk = 34


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.trackandtrace"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3" //1.4.3
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")


    // GPS services
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")

    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")

    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")

}
```

The LocationService.kt:

```
import android.app.Service
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob

@AndroidEntryPoint
class LocationService: Service() {

    private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)

    @Inject
    lateinit var locationClient: LocationClient

    @Inject
    lateinit var positionUseCases: PositionUseCases
  

    ...
}
```

This [website](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2684) mentions to apply the gradle version. I think that can be applied with remove the `version "2.44" apply false`, but this breaks the app even more.
I tried upgrading/downgrading dependencies and kotlin versions but there are too many options. When using versions mentioned on other posts (that usually are already a few years old), the app won't build or give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try migrating to ksp :
Use this link "https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).